# HP ML150 server and RAID

Tags: raid, hp-proliant

Our HP Proliant ML150 is configured as RAID in the BIOS, and created a "Logical drive" (using two 250GB HD) as RAID 1+0.

The procedure seems to be Ok.

However, when installing the OS (Ubuntu 10.10) the partitioner utility still shows our two HD

```
  /dev/sda
  /dev/sdb
```

I was expecting to see only one drive, since the two HD are RAIDed.

Is there a special step missing (checked again at boot, the RAID logical drive is still alive)?

**edit** It seems Ubuntu does not recognize the logical RAID drive.

**edit2** RAID 1+0 is possible with two disks. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID).

```
  RAID 1+0: mirrored sets in a striped set (minimum two disks but more commonly four disks to take advantage of speed benefits; even number of disks)
```

Comment: You want 4 disks to do 1+0 right.  With 2, just do raid 1.

Comment: There is no "1" raid, only "1+0". And there should not be any problem with that.

Comment: The ML150 comes with a software raid onboard (aka, fakeraid). The windows driver picks that up and mirrors the two drives. Non-Windows systems show two independent disks.

Comment: Actually there are drivers for Redhat and Suse provided by HP on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either get a hardware RAID controller like a SmartArray P4xx or use software RAID.  SW RAID works well on Linux - much better than Windows - so you may not need HW RAID.

The main advantage of HW RAID is battery backup which gives you a fairly good chance of surviving a power outage without corrupting your disk.  You might find it worth your while to get a HW RAID controller for this reason.

Comment: Thanks - this is what we'll be doing, Ubuntu's software RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't recognise the RAID logical drive created by the BIOS.
And no driver is available.

```
  Ubuntu is not supported by HP for the B110i Smart array RAID controller Proliant ML150 (G6)
```

So our choices are down to

- install another OS
- use the software based RAID

Comment: +1, Also 3rd choice is to pickup a real RAID card like the P4xx series.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to implement fully functional RAID 0+1 using only 2 hard drives (refer to the RAID guides, for example here http://www.bjorn3d.com/read.php?cID=886). It is pointless to use RAID 0 without getting any advantage in speed and capacity, also using RAID 0 is no option for the server, because if one disk fails - you loose all the data you have. So there is few options:

1. To buy 2 more HDDs, similar to the
   ones you already have and build
   normal RAID 1+0
2. Just not to use RAID
3. Use software RAID (read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)

Comment: It is possible - see my edit2. Take a piece of paper, draw the disks and imagine that without any speed advantage you can get 1+0. The HP Array does not have 1 anyway, only 1+0.

Comment: The BIOS in those servers says 1+0, if you use two drives you'll get just RAID1; if you have 4 or more you'll get 1+0.

Comment: Made a little edit